# Avoid partial matching of list names?

Tags: r, list

Suppose you are trying to make a named list where sometimes elements of that list
have not been assigned a value, and their name is similar to other objects in
the list.

```
# assign values
ab <- 1
x <- 5

# make l1
l1 <- list(ab=ab, x =x)

# make l2
l2 <- list(a = l1$a, b= l1$b, ab = l1$ab, x = l1$x)
```

Looking at `l2`, we find that `l2$a` was assigned a value of 1 although `a` had not previously been assigned a value, nor was it included in `l1`.

```
$a
[1] 1

$b
NULL

$ab
[1] 1

$x
NULL
```

Inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48206590/5456906) I am using a work-around that defines a vector of names that should exist, in order to assign NAs to those that should not exist.

```
not_null <- c(names(l1), "x")
null_names <- setdiff(names(l2), not_null)

l2[names(l2) %in% null_names] <- NA

> l2
$a
[1] NA

$b
[1] NA

$ab
[1] 1

$x
[1] 5
```

But is there more direct way to avoid the problem when constructing `l2`? Like, can we somehow instruct `list()` to search for only exact names?

**Edit**

My original guess what that this behavior was due to "lazy evaluation". However, as noted in the comments, it's likely due to "partial matching".

Comment: The issue seems to be partial matching in `l1$a`, not the behavior of `list()`. Consider `options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE)`

Comment: Or use `l1[["a"]]` instead of `l1$a`. `[[` has an `exact` argument that defaults to `TRUE`

Comment: @Aurele. Yes. So  simple. `l1[["a"]]` avoids the problem. Merci.