# Adding non existing columns to a data frame using mutate with across in dplyr R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a list of column names as follow,

```
cols <- c('grade', 'score', 'status')
```

If the data frame doesn't have any of the columns in the cols vector, I want to add that column (values as NA) to the data frame using mutate and across. How to do that?

Comment: Would you accept an answer **not** using dplyr mutate and across? I think there are existing questions with alternative solutions _e.g._ [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206514/find-whether-a-column-exists-in-r-data-frame-and-if-not-then-create-it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `base` solution:

```r
df[setdiff(cols, names(df))] <- NA
```

This command can be adapted for pipeline:

```r
df %>%
  `[<-`(, setdiff(cols, names(.)), NA)

#   id score grade status
# 1  1    94    NA     NA
# 2  2    98    NA     NA
# 3  3    93    NA     NA
# 4  4    82    NA     NA
# 5  5    89    NA     NA
```

---

###### Data

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5, score = sample(80:100, 5))
```

Comment: I accept this answer even though it doesn't use mutate with across as it looks simpler. thanks

Answer (score 2):

## A solution using `dplyr::mutate()`

Suppose that your data frame is `diamonds`. Then add a tibble data frame that has the same number of columns as the column names (i.e. three columns, in this MWE) to the original data frame (i.e. `diamond` here).

### To create a tibble that contains `NA` automatically

(Thanks to [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73369426/adding-non-existing-columns-to-a-data-frame-using-mutate-with-across-in-dplyr-r/73369832#comment129571773_73369832) by [Darren Tsai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10068985/darren-tsai))

To create a tibble that has the same number of columns as the column names, you can first create a `matrix` that has the same number of columns as the column names by `matrix(ncol = length(cols))`, and second, transform it to a tibble data frame by `as_tibble()` and set the column names using `.name_repair = ~ cols` inside of `as_tibble()`.

The value of each column of the tibble is ***logical***`NA`, when the matrix is created. Note but you may prefer one of `NA_integer_`, `NA_real_`, `NA_complex_`, or `NA_character_` over `NA`, if you want mutate these newly added columns later on as `integer` columns, numeric columns, complex columns (e.g. 1 + 5i), and character columns, respectively. In such a case, you can `mutate` the tibble so that you can change the type of column.

You can create such a tibble inside of `mutate`.

```r
cols <- c('grade', 'score', 'status')

diamonds |>
  mutate(
    matrix(
      ncol = length(cols)
    ) |>
      as_tibble(
        .name_repair = ~ cols
      ) |>
      ## if you want to interpret the grade as `factor` type...
      mutate(
        grade = as.factor(grade)
      )
  )

## # A tibble: 53,940 × 13
##    carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z grade score
##    <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <lgl>
##  1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43 NA    NA
##  2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31 NA    NA   
##  3  0.23 Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31 NA    NA
##  4  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63 NA    NA
##  5  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75 NA    NA
##  6  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48 NA    NA
##  7  0.24 Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47 NA    NA   
##  8  0.26 Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53 NA    NA
##  9  0.22 Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49 NA    NA
## 10  0.23 Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39 NA    NA
## # … with 53,930 more rows, and 1 more variable: status <lgl>
```

### To create the `NA` tibble that does not have any column that matches to the original data frame

(Thanks to [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73369426/adding-non-existing-columns-to-a-data-frame-using-mutate-with-across-in-dplyr-r/73369832#comment129571558_73369832) by [Julian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14137004/julian))

To ensure that the columns are added to the original data frame only if the original data frame doesn't have any of the columns in the `cols` vector, you have to select the columns of the `NA` tibble data frame that are not present in the original data frame. You can do that by using `!select(matches(colnames(diamonds)))`.

```
cols <- c("grade", "price", "status")

matrix(ncol = length(cols)) |>
  as_tibble(
    .name_repair = ~ cols
  ) |>
  mutate(
    grade = as.factor(grade)
  )

diamonds |>
  mutate(
    matrix(
      ncol = length(cols)
    ) |>
      as_tibble(
        .name_repair = ~cols
      ) |>
      ## if you want to interpret the grade as `factor` type...
      mutate(
        grade = as.factor(grade)
      ) |>
      ## select columns that are not present in the original data frame 
      dplyr::select(
        !matches(colnames(diamonds))
      )
  )

## # A tibble: 53,940 × 12
##    carat cut      color clarity depth table price     x     y     z grade status
##    <dbl> <ord>    <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <lgl> 
##  1  0.23 Ideal    E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43 NA    NA
##  2  0.21 Premium  E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31 NA    NA
##  3  0.23 Good     E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31 NA    NA    
##  4  0.29 Premium  I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63 NA    NA
##  5  0.31 Good     J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75 NA    NA
##  6  0.24 Very Go… J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48 NA    NA
##  7  0.24 Very Go… I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47 NA    NA
##  8  0.26 Very Go… H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53 NA    NA    
##  9  0.22 Fair     E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49 NA    NA
## 10  0.23 Very Go… H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39 NA    NA
## # … with 53,930 more rows
```

Comment: The idea is in general good, but OP wants to, if I understood correctly, to have the column untouched when it is already in the data, i.e. in your example if you change cols to `cols <- c('clarity', 'score', 'status')` you will see that clarity is `NA`.

Comment: Also, it's better to create the tibble automatically, instead of typing `a = NA`, `b = NA`, ..., one by one. What if `cols` is of length 100?

Comment: @Julian Thank you for your helpful comments! I reply to your comments by editing my answer.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Thank you for your good and natural question! I changed the way to make tibble and present the method to make a tibble automatically from a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(grade = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 score = c(1, 2, 3))

cols <- c('grade', 'score', 'status')

for (i in cols){
    if (!(i %in% colnames(df))){
        df[i] <- NA
    }
}

> df
  grade score status
1     A     1     NA
2     B     2     NA
3     C     3     NA
```