# Conditional creation (mutate) of new columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a vector containing "potential" column names:

```
col_vector <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

I also have a data frame, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(A = 1:2,
             B = 1:2)
```

My goal now is to create all columns mentioned in `col_vector` that don't yet exist in `df`.

For the above exmaple, my code below works:

```
df %>%
  mutate(!!sym(setdiff(col_vector, colnames(.))) := NA)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
      A     B C    
  <int> <int> <lgl>
1     1     1 NA   
2     2     2 NA
```

Problem is that this code fails as soon as a) more than one column from `col_vector` is missing or b) no column from `col_vector` is missing. I thought about some sort of if_else, but don't know how to make the column creation conditional in such a way - preferably in a tidyverse way. I know I can just create a loop going through all the missing columns, but I'm wondering if there is a more direc approach.

Example data where code above fails:

```
df2 <- tibble(A = 1:2)
df3 <- tibble(A = 1:2,
              B = 1:2,
              C = 1:2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857787/adding-column-if-it-does-not-exist

Comment: Oh my. Stupid me. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

This [**`base`**](https://rdrr.io/r/base/Extract.html) operation might be simpler than a full-fledged [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) workflow:

```
library(tidyverse) # For the setdiff() function.


# ...
# Code to generate 'df'.
# ...


# Find the subset of missing names, and create them as columns filled with 'NA'.
df[, setdiff(col_vector, names(df))] <- NA


# View results
df
```

## Results

Given your sample `col_vector` and `df` here

```
col_vector <- c("A", "B", "C")
df <- tibble(A = 1:2, B = 1:2)
```

this solution should yield the following results:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      A     B C    
  <int> <int> <lgl>
1     1     1 NA   
2     2     2 NA
```

## Advantages

An advantage of my solution, over the [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857787/adding-column-if-it-does-not-exist) linked [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69714636#comment123227074_69714636) by [@geoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9962870/geoff), is that you **need not** code *by hand* the set of column names, as [`symbol`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/name.html)s and strings within the **`dplyr`** workflow.

```
df %>% mutate(
  #####################################
  A = ifelse("A" %in% names(.), A, NA),
  B = ifelse("B" %in% names(.), B, NA),
  C = ifelse("C" %in% names(.), B, NA)

  # ...
  # etc.
  #####################################
)
```

My solution is by contrast more dynamic

```
     ##############################
df[, setdiff(col_vector, names(df))] <- NA
     ##############################
```

if you ever decide to change (or even dynamically calculate!) your variable names midstream, since it determines the [`setdiff()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/generics/man/setops.html) at *runtime*.

## Note

Incredibly, [@AustinGraves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9358374) [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69714741/timeline#history_9c5d4719-6a43-4b3c-800e-6c40792cad2d) their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69714741) at *precisely* the same time (`2021-10-25 21:03:05Z`) as I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69714743/timeline#history_ca491eb7-01c0-4a5f-8089-fceb9b36123e) mine, so both answers qualify as original solutions.

Comment: Your answer popped up for me a few seconds earlier, though.

Answer (score 4):

This should work.

```
df[,setdiff(col_vector, colnames(df))] <- NA
```